How to check the value of the global container in SAP workflow?
I am looking for a way to check how the values in the container change during the runtime in debug mode.
The containers that are bound to a task I can set a breakpoint to see how they change. I want to see what is stored in these global container elements in the beginning of the program run.
Screenshot of the container elements:


To check the values of the global container, got to SWI1 and enter the workflow instance ID and access the log for the specific workflow execution.
In the log, expand the steps and check the container values for each task, you can see the values passed between tasks in the "Workflow Container" section.
Then, within SWI1, select "Technical Workflow Log" to get more detailed information, that includes values stored in the global and task-specific containers at different steps.
Finally, use SWEL to track the events triggered and view the container data for each event, giving insights into the initial values passed when the workflow started.
SWIA allows you to monitor running workflows and inspect container values for active instances.
